# inject/access methods from a parent module inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails I have the following structure

```
#.../models/A.rb
module A
  def m
  end
end

#.../models/a/B.rb
class A::B < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This automatically places A as a parent of B. **Is there a way to do something like B.m without modifying B?** I know that I could do something like B.parent.m and from there create aliases, but then i would have to change B. 
I'm looking to somehow inject a code present in A into B, but I don't know where this automatic association is done behind the scenes.
Something like

```
module A
  module C
    def mc
    end
  end
  def placed_as_parent (child) # supposing this is the method called to put this module as a parent 
    super child
    child.include(C) #this is what I would like to do
  end
end
```

The question behind it is that I have a module which is already being shared among several models of that folder and I would like to put some common stuff for the models in there without have to manually include/extend a module in each of my models

[[EDITED]]

I'm not being clear with my question. In rails 3 if you do

```
rails generate active_record:model A::B
```

it will generate the files

```
#.../models/A.rb
module A
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'a_'
  end
end

#.../models/a/B.rb
class A::B < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So if I open a console and type

```
A::B.table_name # -> 'a_b'
A::B.table_name_prefix # -> ''
A::B.parent # -> A
A.table_name_prefix # 'a_'
```

This happens automatically **without any include/extend** in the model B. What I want is to include more stuff in A and access it from B, without changing anything on B as i described earlier.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  Now we know that you want is possible in the Ruby language and it's just a matter of figuring out how.  We could read the source code of ActiveRecord.

Comment: sure, I know what I wanted is possible! what I want is to know how/what is the best way to do that

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I'll give it a shot anyway.

There is a hook in the Module class that allows you to get a reference to the class the module is being included into. Thus, you could then do virtually anything with it.

An example:

```
module A  
  # you can change the class' behavior here
  def self.included(klass) 
    puts "included in #{klass}" 
  end
end
```

And then to use it:

```
class B
  include A #this causes the included hook in the module to be called
end
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: I know this approach but it is not what I'm looking for because I would have to write 'include A' inside B

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> The question behind it is that I have a module which is already being shared among several models of that folder and I would like to put some common stuff for the models in there without have to manually include/extend a module in each of my models

Here's what I would do:

```
module Stuff1
   ...
end

module Stuff2
   ...
end

module StuffIWantInSeveralModels
   include Stuff1, Stuff2
end

class X < ActiveRecord::Base
    include StuffIWantInSeveralModels
end

class Y < ActiveRecord::Base
    include StuffIWantInSeveralModels
end
```

Then when you want to add a new module to several of your models, you only have to write an "include" statement in one place (in the StuffIWantInSeveralModels module).

Each module should be in its own file in the lib directory, with the file name matching the name of the module so Rails auto-loading will work (e.g. stuff_i_want_in_several_models.rb).

Does this achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it achieve what I want(I'm using this in my app), but I'm looking for a new way to do it using the automatically model linking of rails.